# Cubic residue problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $x,y,z$ integers and $p$ is a prime satisfying

$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod p \Rightarrow xyz \equiv 0 \pmod p$

this proposition. Is there infinity $p$ primes or $p$ is only $2,7,13$ ?

Answer is easy when

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p \Rightarrow xyz \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Only $2$ and $5$ satisfies this proposition. We can use Legendre symbol or other elementary methods.

For $x^3$, there is a tool like a legendre symbol. But i don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

For $p\ge5$, $X^3+Y^3+Z^3=0$ is the homogeneous equation of an elliptic curve in the projective plane. It has $p+1-a$ points over $\Bbb F_p$ where $|a|<2\sqrt p$
(Hasse's theorem). But it has most $9$ points with $XYZ=0$. As long
as $p+1-2\sqrt p=(\sqrt p-1)^2>9$, it has points with $XYZ\ne0$.
This is the case for $p\ge17$.

Comment: what about $x^n+y^n+z^n \equiv 0 (mod p) , n>3$ ?

Comment: That's a curve of genus $g=\frac12(n-1)(n-2)$ in general. Again there is a lower bound on the number of points in terms  of $g$ (Riemann hypothesis for curves) and for each $n$ there is $c_n$ such that the curve has points with $XYZ\ne0$ for $p>c_n$ by a similar argument. @Dogukan.N